# Make VS Code auto-complete include headers from the whole project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I have VS Code configured with the native C++ extension and I'm using CMake as well as generating the compile_commands that VS Code can use to configure intellisense. Completion works as well as navigation, building, etc..

What I'm interested in is making VS Code provide (fuzzy) completions for any headers in the workspace. Currently completion for `#include "` only works for headers in the same folder, in a system folder or in the `src` folder.

Is there a way to make VS Code provide suggestions for any header in the workspace? When a suggestion in a different folder is selected it should include the path (relative to src if in a different parent folder, or relative to the current folder if the header is in a subfolder).

This is exactly what pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> twice in CLion does. It provides completions for any header in the project and it is a really nice feature.

---

PS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> in vscode can open any file in the workspace and currently I use it just to check what is the path that I should use to include a header. It would be much better if suggestions for completing `#include "` already did this.

Comment: I use the Clangd-based autocomplete plugin instead of the default one, and it does it automatically.

Comment: But that means changing the whole completion system, right. I imagine it might impact the quality of other completion and navigation, but I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that clangd extension adds the required include when you enter something that requires that include. It also adds a quickfix that adds the required include when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. But unfortunately it does not offer auto-completion for headers as I have asked.

Comment: Try pressing "Ctrl+Space", it works for me. Make sure Clangd works otherwise (syntax errors are highlighted, and so on). You might need to generate `compile_commans.json` for your project for it to find headers in your custom paths.